# consuming a RESTFUL web service in c# with JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, rest

I have a c# web application where I need to pass in data to a RESTFUL web service (which I have never used before).

Here is the location of the service: 
http://115.111.114.118:7080/prognocis/custom/arizonaurology/details

And here is the JSON request data I need to pass in:

```
{ 
    "chartNo":151531, 
    "encType":"AS",
    "logWSCallInDB":"N"
}
```

I honestly am not even sure where to start here...my knowledge is more with consumable web services with wsdls. Can anyone lend me a hand? Or at least get me pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Might wanna read up a bit first on RESTful services. http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069

Comment: If you look at the second answer to the question this is a duplicate of, you will see them recommend RestSharp, which is probably a good place to start

Comment: You can use Restsharp - Simple REST and HTTP API Client for .NET. The project is opensource and well documented and tested. https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki

Comment: Restsharp seems to be what I need.